# Can not display product by specific category in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to display products by specific category and for that I create a CMS page and called catalog block for this specific category, like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="49" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I have lots of products in this category but when i am trying to browse the URL its not showing me any products http://coralconcept.in/pant-skirt/, You can see over here coralconcept.in/clothing?cat=49 . Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong? Or I need to update any settings from admin or in `catalog.xml` file?

Comment: can you please uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); in index.php so it display error . and let me know which one error that one